# Be careful with your words!

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/fortnightly-topic-challenge-25-wordplay): [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay).</sup></sup>

---

You use words all the time, don't you? Better be careful; words are a lot more powerful than you might think. Used mindlessly, they might *dishearten* someone. They might make you sound *off-center*.

> $$\boxed{\begin{array}{c}\text{Decapitate a ut of a necklace}\\
> \text{Gained conption fast }\\
> \text{The ultimate, last anwer: don't listen much}\\
> \text{Most fain ge gone by}\\
> \text{A cold desse; a versifier}\end{array}}$$

This should be a lesson: what **not** to be when using words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the coattails of Neil W:

> The introduction mentions "disheartening" and "off-centre" and the questions are missing their "hearts", that is their central letters. Let's fill them in:
>
> ```
>            Decapitate a u[ ni]t of a necklace
>                Gained con[ ce]ption fast
>     The ultimate, last an[ s ]wer: don't listen much
>                 Most fain[t a]ge gone by
>              A cold desse[ rt]; a versifier
> ```
>
> The missing hearts spell **Nice start**.

Each question ...

> ... has two answers, the first part defines the whole word, the second part defines the word with its "heart" removed:
>
> ```
>     BE[HE]AD    - Decapitate | a unit of a necklace
>     LE[AR]NT    - Gained conception | fast
>     HEAR[T]LESS - The ultimate, last answer | don't listen much
>     PA[LE]ST    - Most faint | age gone by
>     PO[SS]ET    - A cold dessert | a versifier
> ```
>
> Again, the hearts of the answers spell out something: When using words, you should not be **heartless**.
>
>  (The answer to the third question is also the final answer of the whole puzzle. Nice!)

Comment: Nicely done. You already have one half of the third one btw ;)

Comment: Oh, I see! `:)`

Comment: Well done......... :)

Answer (score 6):

So going by the hints,

> I originally thought This has something to do with words with missing centres (disheartened).

So my theory

> was there is a word which de-centred gives another word, each of which relates to part of the clue, one of the parts, at least, having, at least, one de-centred word. But after a discussion in the comments, the missing 'centre' is not always the case, there is something more to it.

Decapitate a ut of a necklace

> Decapitate = be[he]ad = a u[ni]t of a necklace

A cold desse; versifier

> A cold desse[rt] = po[ss]et = versifier  [wikipedia:posset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posset)

Comment: Your approach is pretty close to the right one, so I guess I might just say this: The missing parts of the sentences are *centers*, but not of the words (rot13: r.t., jbhyqa'g vg znxr n ybg zber frafr gb unir qrfr(eg) engure guna qr(sra)fr?). And figuring out the missing parts might lead you somewhere.

Comment: qrfreg be qrffreg?

Comment: Whoops, that's an error on my part; edited that. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: No worries........